React typescript type for FieldErrors in form
I'm creating a form using https://react-fcc-forms.vercel.app/
I have a generic Input like this:
const Input = ({ label, type, id, value }: any) => {
  const { register, formState: { errors } } = useFormContext()
  const inputError = findInputError(errors, label)
  const isInvalid = isFormInvalid(inputError)

  return (
    <label htmlFor={id}>
      <div className="label">{label}</div>
      <AnimatePresence mode="wait" initial={false}>
        {isInvalid && (
          <InputError
            message={inputError.error.message}
            key={inputError.error.message}
          />
        )}
      </AnimatePresence>
      <input
        type={type}
        id={id}
        value={value}
        {...register(label, {
          required: {
            value: true,
            message: 'verplicht',
          },
        })}
      />
    </label>
  )
}

In my project, I use typescript so my findInputError looks slightly different:
import { FieldErrors, FieldValues } from "react-hook-form";

export function findInputError(errors: FieldErrors<FieldValues>, name: string) {
  const filtered = Object.keys(errors)
    .filter(key => key.includes(name))
    .reduce((cur, key) => {
      return Object.assign(cur, { error: errors[key] })
    }, {})
  return filtered
}

But now, I get an error on these lines:
message={inputError.error.message}
key={inputError.error.message}

Property 'error' does not exist on type '{}'. How can i change findInputError to make it work?
